# Need someone explain the meaning of a sentence 調子に乗るのも、いい加減にィ…… which got cut-off near the end by the character

Tags: grammar, meaning, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**There's a sentence which I'm not sure about its meaning , hope someone can explain to me. 調子に乗るのも、いい加減に... (the character stopped near the end of the sentence, so it's hard for my JP level. I can only guess the meaning : "Even if you're over-excited, there's a limit...")**

Context: MC has been turned into a kid due to an app from his smartphone (previously there's a sentence refers to Conan by the author ^^) and now he's acting like a baby, trying to demand his classmate to let him drink her breast milk (the girl is also a bro-con but she doesn't know about it)

アプリの効果で母性本能を極限にまで引き上げられているので、小さくなった俺に甘えられるのがたまらないようだ。

A (the MC's classmate)「あっく、あッ、あぁッ。強くっ、吸い過ぎだ……！　ハァハァッ、ちょっ、**調子に乗るのも、いい加減にィ……**くうぅん！」

口では拒絶をするものの、A はまったく抵抗しなかった。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence has しなさい/しろ omitted. That is, in full, it is 調子に乗るのもいい加減にしなさい.

Xもいい加減にしなさい is more or less a fixed pattern meaning 'Be moderate in X'. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97336/45489) for details.

So the sentence literally means 'Be moderate as regards 調子に乗る', which means something like 'Don't go too far'.

調子に乗る in general means to have too much confidence; in this case, confidence in making advance to the MC.

Answer (score 1):

しなさい is omitted after いい加減に.
いい加減にしなさい means "Get a life!" or "That's enough!". いい加減にして(よね) or いい加減にしろ is also okay.